# i got empty Django rest api....i want userlist

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([])

def user_list(request, format=None):

  """
  List all users, or create a new user.
  """
 
 if request.method == 'GET':
   
 existed_u_user = UUsers.objects.all()
    
serializer = UserSerializer(existed_u_user, many=True)
   
 return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Please refer to the documentation and rewrite the question so that the community can understand better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serializing a queryset with many=True you should convert the result into a list:

```
return Response(list(serializer.data))
```